# How prepare the Data to plot a Diversity graph from a dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got a dataframe has the format below using "pivot_longer" function:

```
df1 = 
  Dept.            qtr     bud_or_act   amount
   <chr>          <chr>    <chr>       <dbl>
 1 Distribution     Q1     Budget     390000
 2 Distribution     Q1     Actual     375000
 3 Distribution     Q2     Budget     395000
 4 Distribution     Q2    Actual     382000
 5 Distribution     Q3    Budget     400000
 6 Distribution     Q3    Actual     390000
 7 Distribution     Q4    Budget     410000
 8 Distribution     Q4    Actual     408000
 9 Facilities       Q1    Budget     675000
10 Facilities       Q1    Actual     693000

# ... with 22 more rows
```

Is there any possibility to reorganize this dataframe to be like:

```
df2 = 
qtr   Budget   Actual  
Q1    390000  375000
Q2    395000  382000
Q3    400000  390000
Q4    410000  408000
Q1    675000  693000
```

I asked you this question because I am looking to put this data into Diversity graph using this formula:

```
# Shaded region
ggplot(df2, aes(x=qtr, y=Budget )) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Budget -Actual , ymax=Budget +Actual ), alpha=0.2) +
    geom_line()
```

Comment: You'd use `pivot_wider()` to turn the data frame as you want it, but I don't understand how you're thinking of using `geom_ribbon()`.

Comment: how do you want to handel the column `Dept.` ?